# Create scheduled task w/ Admin access from PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a script that sets up the (AWS) instance (joins domain, hardening etc).

Part of it (load GPO backups, create OUs and users) needs to run after a reboot, so I figured I create a scheduled task for it.

But I can't get it to get the access it needs!

```
$psexe = Join-Path $PSHOME powershell.exe
$T = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtStartup
$P = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" -RunLevel Highest -LogonType ServiceAccount
$S = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$A = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute $psexe -Argument "-NoProfile -NonInteractive -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Windows\Temp\install_gpo.ps1"
$D = New-ScheduledTask -Action $A -Principal $P -Trigger $T -Settings $S
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Install GPO" -InputObject $D -ErrorAction Ignore
```

The script itself is fairly simple:

```
Start-Transcript -path C:\log-install_gpo.txt
Import-GPO -BackupGpoName LogonBanner -TargetName LogonBanner -Path C:\Windows\Temp\GpoBackups -CreateIfNeeded
gpupdate
Stop-Transcript
```

Running the task (!) manually from the task scheduler GUI and looking at the log file, I see:

```
Username: DOMAIN\SYSTEM
RunAs User: DOMAIN\SYSTEM
[...]
Import-GPO : Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
(E_ACCESSDENIED))
At C:\Windows\Temp\install_gpo.ps1:2 char:1
+ Import-GPO -BackupGpoName LogonBanner -TargetName LogonBanner -Path C ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-GPO], UnauthorizedAcce
   ssException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Gro
   upPolicy.Commands.ImportGpoCommand
```

So it seems that the 'System' user doesn't have access to do what I want/need! Not sure why that is, I specify the highest `RunLevel` and `Unrestricted` execution policy..

Running the `Import-GPO` command in an elevated PS shell works just fine!

I can't run it as *Administrator*, because that would require a password (that doesn't work anyway, `Register-ScheduledTask` refuses to accept that on the command line), I can't specify both `-UserID` *and* `-GroupID` (*...\Administrator* for example) at the same time.

I've tried using the *RunOnce* registry key, but that seem to work even less. Also, if I understand the docs for that correctly, it is only run when a/any user logs in, which might never happen! This is (supposed to be) a "headless server" so no-one *should* ever login to it..

I'm at a loss to what to try next.